# Solve inequalities and find parameters

Tags: inequalities

Let

$$S=4 (\alpha -2) \beta -58 (\alpha -2)^2-\beta ^2-8 c_6 \left(7 \alpha +2 c_6-13\right)$$

$$T=-\frac{\left((\alpha -4) (\alpha -2) (\alpha  (3 \alpha +4 \beta -27)-18 \beta +60)+4 c_2 (\alpha +\beta -5)\right){}^2}{4 (\alpha +\beta -5)^2}+c_2 (\alpha +\beta -5) \left(8 \alpha +\beta +4 c_6-16\right){}^2-c_2 (\alpha +\beta -5) \left(2 (\alpha -2) (3 \alpha +10 \beta -6)+8 c_6 (\alpha +\beta -3)\right)$$

$$U=\left(-\frac{1}{12} \left(-12 c_4 (\alpha +\beta -4)-36 c_2\right) \left(-2 \alpha +\beta -2 \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)+4\right){}^2-\frac{1}{6} c_6 \left(\frac{3 (\alpha -6) (\alpha -5) (\alpha -4) (\alpha -2)}{\alpha +\beta -5}-6 (\alpha -4) (2 \alpha -9) (\alpha -2)-12 c_2\right) \left(-2 \alpha +\beta -2 \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)+4\right)-\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{3 (\alpha -6) (\alpha -5) (\alpha -4) (\alpha -2)}{\alpha +\beta -5}-6 (\alpha -4) (2 \alpha -9) (\alpha -2)-12 c_2\right) \left(-3 (\alpha -2) (3 \alpha -11)-2 c_6 (\alpha +\beta -3)-6 c_4\right)+\frac{1}{12} \left(-12 c_4 (\alpha +\beta -4)-36 c_2\right) \left(-2 (\alpha -2) (7 \alpha -24)-4 (\alpha +\beta -3) \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)\right)\right){}^2-4 \left(-\frac{1}{36} \left(\frac{3 (\alpha -6) (\alpha -5) (\alpha -4) (\alpha -2)}{\alpha +\beta -5}-6 (\alpha -4) (2 \alpha -9) (\alpha -2)-12 c_2\right){}^2+c_2 (\alpha +\beta -5) \left(-2 \alpha +\beta -2 \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)+4\right){}^2-c_2 (\alpha +\beta -5) \left(-2 (\alpha -2) (7 \alpha -24)-4 (\alpha +\beta -3) \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)\right)\right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} c_6^2 \left(-2 (\alpha -2) (7 \alpha -24)-4 (\alpha +\beta -3) \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2} c_6 \left(-2 \alpha +\beta -2 \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)+4\right) \left(-3 (\alpha -2) (3 \alpha -11)-2 c_6 (\alpha +\beta -3)-6 c_4\right)-\frac{1}{4} \left(-3 (\alpha -2) (3 \alpha -11)-2 c_6 (\alpha +\beta -3)-6 c_4\right){}^2+c_4 \left(-2 \alpha +\beta -2 \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)+4\right){}^2-c_4 \left(-2 (\alpha -2) (7 \alpha -24)-4 (\alpha +\beta -3) \left(-5 \alpha -2 c_6+10\right)\right)\right)$$,
where $c_2,c_4,c_6\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha,\beta>0$. My question is as follows:

Do there exist $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $c_2,c_4,c_6\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $S>0$, $T>0$, $U\le0$?

I used the codes

```
FindInstance[S>0 && T>0 && U<=0 && α > 0 && β >0, {c2,c4,c6,α,β}, Reals]
```

But it run for over 5 mins and no result can be obtained. So I pick up several α over $[1/10,10]$ like this

```
α=17/7; FindInstance[S>0 && T>0 && U<=0 && α > 0 && β >0, {c2,c4,c6,β}, Reals]
```

It replied me with an empty set

```
{}
```

It seems the interval of $\alpha$ is so narrow and it's not easy to find it. Any other approach to get even only one solution $(\alpha,\beta,c_2,c_4,c_6)$?

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

```
S=-58 (-2 + α)^2 + 4 (-2 + α) β - β^2 - 8 Subscript[c, 6] (-13 + 7 α + 2 Subscript[c, 6])

T=-((-4 + α) (-2 + α) (60 - 
    18 β + α (-27 + 3 α + 4 β)) + 
 4 (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 
  2])^2/(4 (-5 + α + β)^2) + (-5 + α + \β) Subscript[c, 2] (-16 + 8 α + β + 4 Subscript[c, 6])^2 - (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 2] (2 (-2 + α) (-6 + 3 α + 10 β) + 8 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6])

U=(-(1/12) (-36 Subscript[c, 2] - 
  12 (-4 + α + β) Subscript[c, 4]) (4 - 
  2 α + β - 
  2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 + 1/12 (-36 Subscript[c, 2] - 
  12 (-4 + α + β) Subscript[c, 
   4]) (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
  4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
     2 Subscript[c, 6])) - 1/6 (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
  3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 12 Subscript[c, 2]) (4 - 2 α + β - 
  2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6])) Subscript[c, 6] - 1/6 (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
  3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 12 Subscript[c, 2]) (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 6 Subscript[c, 4] - 2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - 4 (-(1/36) (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
   3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 12 Subscript[c, 2])^2 + (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 2] (4 - 2 α + β - 2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 2] (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6]))) (Subscript[c, 4] (4 - 2 α + β - 
   2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - 
Subscript[c, 4] (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6])) - 
1/4 (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
   4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6])) \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(6\), \(2\)]\) - 
1/2 (4 - 2 α + β - 
   2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6])) Subscript[c, 
 6] (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 6 Subscript[c, 4] - 
   2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6]) - 
1/4 (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 6 Subscript[c, 4] - 
   2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6])^2)
```

Comment: Can you, please, include your code for $S$, $T$ and $U$ ?

Comment: I have post the codes for $S$, $T$, and $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but some hints.

**Edit:**
I corrected wrong U.

These conditions seem too complicated to get an overall analytical solution. Find starting values with graphical methods. (I renamed the subscripts.)

```
S[α_, β_, 
c6_] = -58 (-2 + α)^2 + 
 4 (-2 + α) β - β^2 - 
 8 Subscript[c, 
   6] (-13 + 7 α + 2 Subscript[c, 6]) /. {Subscript[c, 
   2] -> c2, Subscript[c, 4] -> c4, Subscript[c, 6] -> c6} // 
Expand;

T[α_, β_, c2_, c4_, 
c6_] = -((-4 + α) (-2 + α) (60 - 

          18 β + α (-27 + 3 α + 4 β)) + 
        4 (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 

         2])^2/(4 (-5 + α + β)^2) + (-5 + α + \
β) Subscript[c, 
    2] (-16 + 8 α + β + 
      4 Subscript[c, 6])^2 - (-5 + α + β) Subscript[
    c, 2] (2 (-2 + α) (-6 + 3 α + 10 β) + 
     8 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6]) /. {Subscript[
    c, 2] -> c2, Subscript[c, 4] -> c4, Subscript[c, 6] -> c6} // 
Together // Simplify;

U[α_, β_, c2_, c4_, 
c6_] = -(1/(
4 (-5 + α + β)^2)) (232 + 16   c6^2 + 58 α^2 + 
 8 c6 (-13 + 7 α) + 8 β +   β^2 - 
 4 α (58 + β)) (-c6^2 (8 - 
    6 α + α^2)^2 (60 + 3  α^2 - 
    18 β + α (-27 + 4   β))^2 - 
 4 c2^2 (-5 + α + β)^2 (-56 c4  + 196 c6^2 + 
    12 c6 (-88 + 48 α - β) + 
    9 (144 + 46 α^2 + 8 β +  β^2 - 
       4 α (41 + β))) - 
 4 c4^2 (20 + α^2 - 
    9 β + β^2 + α (-9 + 2  β)) (1760 + 
    40 α^4 - 1064 β + 
    180 β^2 - β^3 + β^4 + 
    44 α^3 (-11 + 2 β) + 
    3 α^2 (668 - 230 β + 
       17 β^2) - α (3272 - 1560  β + 
       189 β^2 + 2 β^3) + 
    16 c6^2 (20 + α^2 - 
       9 β + β^2 + α (-9  + 2 β)) + 
    8 c6 (-13 + 7 α) (20 + α^2  - 
       9 β + β^2 + α (-9  + 2 β))) + 
 4 c4 (8 - 6 α + α^2) (60 + 3  α^2 - 
    18 β + α (-27 + 
       4 β)) (-4 c6^2 (20 + α^2  - 
       9 β + β^2 + α (-9  + 2 β)) + 
    c6 (200 - 6 α^3 + α^2 (64 - 11 β) - 
       70 β + β^2 + β^3 +  α (-210 + 
          65 β - 4 β^2)) + (-2 + α) (-420 + 
       6 α^3 + 225 β - 
       33 β^2 + α^2 (-75 + 
          14 β) + α (309 - 113  β + 
          9 β^2))) - 
 4 c2 (-5 + α + β) (-8 c6^3 (-5  + α + \
β)^2 (-3 + α + β) + 
    12 c4^2 (35 + α^2 + 2 α  (-6 + β) - 
       12 β + β^2) + 
    9 (-2 + α)^2 (-11 + 3 α)  (-35 + 
       2 α^2 (-1 + β) + 38  β - 
       11 β^2 + α (17 - 18  β + 3 β^2)) - 
    2 c6^2 (26 α^4 + 
       5 α^3 (-83 + 14 β) +  α^2 (2383 - 
          742 β + 55 β^2) + 
       4 α (-1442 + 610 β - 
          78 β^2 + β^3) - 
       6 (-815 + 407 β - 65 β^2   + β^3)) - 
    3 c6 (-2 + α) (3100 + 18  α^4 - 1170 β + 
       72 β^2 + 22 β^3 + 
       9 α^3 (-32 + 5 β) +  α^2 (1642 - 
          457 β + 28 β^2) - 
       2 α (1940 - 693 β + 61  β^2 + 
          3 β^3)) + 
    2 c4 (7180 + 79 α^4 - 3596  β + 
       450 β^2 + β^3 + β^4  + 
       56 c6^2 (-5 + α + β) +  α^3 (-995 + 
          164 β) + 
       3 α^2 (1534 - 470 β + 
          29 β^2) - α (9446 -  3962 β + 
          399 β^2 + 2 β^3) + 
       2 c6 (30 + 16 α^3 + 34  α^2 (-3 + β) + 
          209 β - 53 β^2 + 
          2 β^3 + α (104 - 155  β + 
             20 β^2)))))
```

S > 0 gives conditions min, max of parameters.

```
RegionPlot3D[
    S[α, β, c6] > 0, {α, 0, 10}, {β, 0, 
    10}, {c6, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 60]

Sminmax = {{αmin, αmax}, {βmin,  βmax}, \
   {c6min, c6max}} = {{First@
   Minimize[{α, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0  && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals], 
  First@Maximize[{α, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0  && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals]},   {First@
   Minimize[{β, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0  && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals], 
   First@Maximize[{β, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0 && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals]},  {First@
   Minimize[{c6, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0  && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals], 
  First@Maximize[{c6, 
     S[α, β, c6] > 0 && α > 0  && β > 
       0}, {α, β, c6}, Reals]}} //   Quiet;

Sminmax // N

(*   {{1.93158, 4.86969}, {0., 7.20908}, {-5.4,  0.}}   *)
```

Now generate a table( takes a few minutes) of regionplots to get hints where to look for solutions.

```
(tab = Table[
 Show[RegionPlot3D[
   U[α, β, c2, c4, c6] <= 0 && 
    T[α, β, c2, c4, c6] > 0, {c2, -10,  10}, {c4, -11,
     11}, {c6, c6min, c6max}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   PlotLabel -> N[{α, β}]], 
  RegionPlot3D[
   S[α, β, c6] > 0, {c2, -10, 10},  {c4, -11, 
    11}, {c6, c6min, c6max}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.3]],  Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, PlotLabel -> N[{α,  β}]], 
  ViewPoint -> {0, -20, -2}], {α,  αmin, \
αmax, .4}, {β, βmin, βmax, .4}];) // Timing

tab
```

Comment: Thanks! I use your codes and obtain a 3D plot. Now it is generating a table, but I didn't get a table after it run for over ten minutes. Does this result mean that it's possible there exists a solution?

Comment: On my pc it ran for 15 minutes. Change .4 at alpha and beta to e.g. 2  and PlotPoints to 20 to get a faster result.

Comment: It take over 20mins and cannot get a result. Ok I will try to change the setting.

Comment: Produce only one picture with `{\[Alpha], 3.93, 3.93}, {\[Beta], 2, 2} ` at Table.

Comment: Where to change the two?

Comment: But I result is {3.7158,0.616105,1792.7}. The first two are the same with yours.

Comment: It is possible I have posted the wrong U. Now I repost it for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I re-post $U$ here. The above $U$ perhaps has some mistakes when I copied it from Mathematica codes in order to match the format here.

```
U=(-(1/12) (-36 Subscript[c, 2] - 
  12 (-4 + α + β) Subscript[c, 4]) (4 - 
  2 α + β - 
  2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 + 1/12 (-36 Subscript[c, 2] - 
  12 (-4 + α + β) Subscript[c, 
   4]) (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
  4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
     2 Subscript[c, 6])) - 1/6 (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
  3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 12 Subscript[c, 2]) (4 - 
  2 α + β - 
  2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6])) Subscript[c, 6] - 1/6 (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
  3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 
  12 Subscript[c, 2]) (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 
  6 Subscript[c, 4] - 
  2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - 4 (-(1/36) (-6 (-4 + α) (-2 + α) (-9 + 2 α) + (
   3 (-6 + α) (-5 + α) (-4 + α) (-2 + \α))/(-5 + α + β) - 
   12 Subscript[c, 2])^2 + (-5 + α + β) Subscript[c, 
 2] (4 - 2 α + β - 
   2 (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - (-5 + α + β) Subscript[
 c, 2] (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
   4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6]))) (Subscript[c, 
 4] (4 - 2 α + β - 
   2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6]))^2 - 
Subscript[c, 
 4] (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
   4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6])) - 
1/4 (-2 (-2 + α) (-24 + 7 α) - 
   4 (-3 + α + β) (10 - 5 α - 
      2 Subscript[c, 6])) \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(6\), \(2\)]\) - 
1/2 (4 - 2 α + β - 
   2 (10 - 5 α - 2 Subscript[c, 6])) Subscript[c, 
 6] (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 6 Subscript[c, 4] - 
   2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6]) - 
1/4 (-3 (-2 + α) (-11 + 3 α) - 6 Subscript[c, 4] - 
   2 (-3 + α + β) Subscript[c, 6])^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A failed try which almost succeed is

```
v = Table[Subscript[c, k], {k, 1, 6}]
sol = NMaximize[{α + β, S > 0, T > 0, U <= 0, α > 0, β > 0}, Join[v, {α, β}], Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
{S, T, U, α, β} /. sol[[2]]
```